# any possible way to retain secondary axis label when primary axis is updated

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am displaying a label on a secondary `x`-axis in `ggplot2`, and it works as expected.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <-  ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~., 
                                           labels = "median", 
                                            breaks = 3.2))

# label present 
p
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning in min(x): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
#> Warning in max(x): no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

[image]

But if I update the primary `x`-axis, the secondary `x`-axis is removed.

```r
# label absent
p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 6), breaks = c(seq(1, 6, 1)))
#> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will
#> replace the existing scale.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I would have expected it to be **updated**, and not **removed** (since the secondary axis is a transformation of the primary axis).

Is there any possibility to update the primary axis, while also retaining the secondary axis information?

**P.S.**
This in the context of a package function, where the function defaults to showing a label on the secondary axis. The users can then update the plot using `ggplot2` functions if they want. This means that users can sometimes change the axes, and I would like the function to still display the label. I will update my question to provide this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can circumvent the secondary axis problem if your transformation is 1:1 with the primary axis, by building a new guide. This can then be set in the `guides()` function and will thus act independent of the x-scale. A quick and dirty example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

fix_axis <- function(breaks, labels) {
  guide <- guide_axis()
  guide$breaks <- breaks
  guide$labels <- labels
  class(guide) <- c("guide", "fix_axis", "axis")
  guide
}

guide_train.fix_axis <- function(guide, scale, aesthetic = NULL) {
  guide <- NextMethod()
  key <- as.list(guide$key)
  key[[1]] <- key$.value <- guide$breaks
  key$.label <- guide$label
  guide$key <- list2DF(key) # requires R version >4
  guide
}

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  guides(x.sec = fix_axis(3.2, "median"))

# Scale can update without affecting secondary axis
p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2, 5))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> Warning: Removed 7 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a marvellous trick to store in the back pocket - thanks @teunbrand for this nifty workaround!

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps not an answer which gives a solution, but I thought it best to show some of the complications of the problem.

Your call of course is replacing the scale already there, meaning all parts in the original `scale_x_continuous` call are being dumped and the whole new scale call are being added. This is a part of `ggplot2` which is quite buried down in its code and likely shouldn't be tampered with.

As you can see below, when you add a new scale the ggplot object calls the `p$scales$add()` method which checks whether any of the new aesthetics are already present in scale definitions. The is the whole list of `x`:`x0` which a new scale layer adds. All of these (I think) are required for a scale to work:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot() + scale_x_continuous()

p$scales$add
#> <ggproto method>
#>   <Wrapper function>
#>     function (...) 
#> f(..., self = self)
#> 
#>   <Inner function (f)>
#>     function (self, scale) 
#> {
#>     if (is.null(scale)) {
#>         return()
#>     }
#>     prev_aes <- self$find(scale$aesthetics)
#>     if (any(prev_aes)) {
#>         scalename <- self$scales[prev_aes][[1]]$aesthetics[1]
#>         message_wrap("Scale for '", scalename, "' is already present. Adding another scale for '", 
#>             scalename, "', which will replace the existing scale.")
#>     }
#>     self$scales <- c(self$scales[!prev_aes], list(scale))
#> }

sc <- scale_x_continuous()

sc$aesthetics
#>  [1] "x"          "xmin"       "xmax"       "xend"       "xintercept"
#>  [6] "xmin_final" "xmax_final" "xlower"     "xmiddle"    "xupper"    
#> [11] "x0"

p$scales$find(sc$aesthetics)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I would suggest that your solution might look at defining another [ggproto object](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html) to create a new type of scale for the secondary axis which won't be caught by the method checking for existing scales. I'm afraid my own experience/knowledge of this ends there!

By and large you want your package users to be able to use `scale_x_continuous` and other normal ggplot functions without worrying that it would break their graph. So defining a new function for the user to use when adding an extra scale is probably not the best approach, and the workings of the existing ggplot `scale_` functions are best left alone.

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to update the axis, rather than define the limits/breaks of the primary axis in the first place? If not, you could do it as follows:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~., labels = "median", breaks = 3.2),
                     limits = c(1, 6), breaks = c(seq(1, 6, 1)))
```

Comment: Yes, this in the context of a package function, where the function defaults to showing a label on the secondary axis. The users can then update the plot using `ggplot2` functions if they want. This means that users can sometimes change the axes and I would like the function to still display the label. I will update my question to provide this context.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that since I believe ```sec_axis()``` only accepts one-to-one transformations of the original axis. Hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(1, 6),
    breaks = c(seq(1, 6, 1)),
    sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ ., labels = "median", breaks = 3.2)
  )
```

Your second `scale_x_continuous()` replaced the first one.

Comment: Please see the P.S. in my question.